# How to use multiple keyframe animations in one?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to use two different keyframes animations, but when i name the second animation it does not seem to work. Basically i want to add the first animation to the first wrapper, and the second animation to the second wrapper at the same time, why this does not work?

```css
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200%, 0);
  }
}
.marquee {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: scroll 20s infinite linear;
}
.wrapper div {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.wrapper2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: second 40s infinite linear;
}
.wrapper2 div {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}
.wrapper2 div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Akinfenwa</div>
    <div>Dickenson</div>
    <div>Watkins</div>
    <div>Cowan-Hall</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div>Akinfenwa</div>
    <div>Dickenson</div>
    <div>Watkins</div>
    <div>Cowan-Hall</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's well known all browsers are based on webkit. There is absolutely no problem in prefixing all properties with `-webkit-`. In fact, you should also use `-webkit-display: -webkit-block`, and just in case, `-webkit-webkit-display: -webkit-webkit-block`. </sarcasm>

Comment: @Oriol you are missing display: -webkit-block; and -webkit-display: block; - just in case

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200%, 0);
  }
}
.marquee {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: scroll 10s infinite linear;
}
.wrapper div {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.wrapper2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: second 20s infinite linear;
}
.wrapper2 div {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}
.wrapper2 div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Akinfenwa</div>
    <div>Dickenson</div>
    <div>Watkins</div>
    <div>Cowan-Hall</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div>Akinfenwa2</div>
    <div>Dickenson2</div>
    <div>Watkins2</div>
    <div>Cowan-Hall2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```